# How many triangles are there whose vertices are the vertices of the small cubes in a Rubik's cube?

Tags: combinatorics, triangles, rubiks-cube

There are 4x4x4= 64 vertices, and I'm not sure where to go after this. Do you do 64 choose 3?

Comment: You may want to subtract the cases where the poits are collinear ...

Comment: Are you assuming there is a cube in the very center? If you're only using external vertices, there are $56$

Comment: There is a cube in the center.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I see now, but there are a lot of collinear points. How do I make sure I subtract all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine looking at the 4x4x4 grid from above:
$$\begin{array}{cccc}.&.&.&.\\.&.&.&.\\.&.&.&.\\.&.&.&.\\\end{array}$$
Each dot represents a column of four points. Now we begin counting degenerate triangles which use three distinct points in the 4x4x4 grid.

*Vertical lines.* There are 16 vertical lines, one for each column (dot) in the diagram, each providing $4 \choose 3$ such degenerate triangles.

*Other lines through 4 points.* Viewed from above, there are 10 lines which pass through four columns. For any such line, we can choose three columns and then decide how high each point is.

- If the degenerate triangle uses both the first and last columns in the line, there are 2 choices for the inner column, then 6 ways to position the points vertically (4 of them horizontal, 2 at a 45° slant).
- Otherwise, there are 2 choices for the omitted column, then 8 ways to position the points vertically (4 of them horizontal, 4 at a 45° slant).

*Lines through 3 points.* Viewed from above, there are 4 lines which pass through three columns. Then there are 8 ways to position the points vertically.

Summing, there are $16\cdot 4+10(2\cdot 6+2\cdot 8)+4\cdot 8=376$ degenerate triangles using three distinct points.

Thus there are ${64\choose 3}-376=41288$ non-degenerate triangles.

Comment: Regarding the first paragraph in your answer (the vertical lines), i see how you get 16 * 4 degenerate triangles when looking down on one face of the cube. (Call this the z direction) And these are the same triangles you get from looking down on the opposite face. But there are two other orthogonal directions that yield degenerate triangles - The x and y directions. Why are these not counted?

Comment: From above, those can be seen to pass through 4 points in the diagram, so they are counted in the second paragraph.